# Converting UTC DateTime to local DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I have the following ASP.Net MVC Controller method:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(DateTime utcDate)
{
   var localTime = utcDate.ToLocalTime();
}
```

The problem is that localTime will have the exact same value as utcDate.  I assume this is because utcDate doesn't know it has a UTC value.  So my question is how can I convert utcDate (which I KNOW is UTC) into local?

Comment: do you know what time zone you are in?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you *know* the `DateTime` contains a UTC value, you can use [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx):

```
DateTime iKnowThisIsUtc = whatever;
DateTime runtimeKnowsThisIsUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
    iKnowThisIsUtc,
    DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime localVersion = runtimeKnowsThisIsUtc.ToLocalTime();
```

For example, in my current application, I create timestamps in my database with SQL's `utcnow`, but when I read them into my C# application the `Kind` proeprty is always `Unknown`. I created a wrapper function to read the timestamp, deliberately set its `Kind` to `Utc`, and then convert it to local time - essentially as above.

Note that [`DateTime.ToLocalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx) only doesn't affect the value if one (or both) of the following holds:

- The `DateTime`'s `Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Local`
- Your local timezone is such that "no change" is the correct conversion

I think we can assume the second point isn't true. Thus it seems that `iKnowThisIsUtc`'s `Kind` property is set to `Local` already. You need to figure out why whatever is supplying you with these `DateTime`s thinks they are local.

Comment: NB AFAIK the only way `ToLocalTime()` will _not change_ the value is if the runtime thinks the time is _already local_.* (I.e. it has `DateTimeKind.Local`.) You might want to check if this is the case and, if so, why the dates you're getting are marked as `Local` even though they're not. (* or if local time is UTC of course)

Comment: +1 for beating me to the explanation you added in the comment, although I really think it belongs as part of the answer.

Comment: When I looked into this a while back I found it to be very confusing.  Your answer does do a good job as explaining it, but some examples would probably help.

Comment: When you are adding +1 to the answer, consider also upvoting the question - if you find it useful.

Comment: You also need to check the server time zone is set correctly, i.e. if the server is set to UTC it will not do any conversion as it thinks UTC and local time is the same.

Comment: @QuintusMarais Well... yes. You can't expect the server to do *anything* "local time" if it doesn't know what local time is.

Comment: @Rawling Just pointing out something that I have seen people tripped up by.  They may not think to check that the server time zone is set correctly and then it may not be obvious that the code may be correct and the server setting incorrect.

Comment: Variable names in this example code are **perfect**. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it the same as `DateTime localVersion = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(iKnowThisIsUtc, TimeZoneInfo.Local)`?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
public static DateTime UtcToPacific(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));
        }
```

Obviously change Pacific to your local timezone.

If you want to find out what time zones are present on your machine see the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397781.aspx

Answer (score 5):

as described by MSDN, you need the Kind property of your Date to be UTC, for the ToLocalTime() to work (and convert the date to local time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx

Try this:

```
utcDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var localTime = utcDate.ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

or this:

```
var localTime = new DateTimeOffset(utcDate,TimeSpan.FromHours(0))
                    .ToLocalTime().DateTime;
```

Comment: Your solution working for me. Tks !